# Onnx data transformations (eg. drop column)

Tags: pandas, onnx, onnxruntime

I have a sklearn python model that takes in a pandas dataframe. I do some data transformations like dropping columns and filling missing values before inference. I have to serialize my model and do predictions in a .net application. I havent found a way to take in Json data(.net side) and serialize all dataframe operations like dropping certain columns in the serialized model. Is it even possibile to have a full pipeline with pandas operations serialized to onnx?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?
Generally speaking, you need to implement the operations yourself.
See here
https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-onnx-from-scratch-4063eab80fcd